# second hard drive in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: hard-drive

I have a second hard drive in Ubuntu. The disk manager has it listed. I want to create a new folder in that second drive. I would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to do this. If you are familiar with using the terminal, I would recommend you `cd` into the directory where your second hard drive is located. You can them enter `mkdir [NAME IT WHATEVER YOU WANT]` to create the directory (directory means the same thing as a folder.)

If you are unfamiliar with the terminal, you can use nautilus (ubuntu's default file manager) to create a new folder. To open nautilus press the super key (usually the windows key) and start typing nautilus. Then navigate to your second hard drive, right-click, and select Create New > Folder.